# Windows Phone how to detect if user is connecting via APN?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

how can I detect in code if the user is connecting via an apn setting? as to a normal 3G connection?

thanx

Comment: Would you mind clarifying? You want to detect if the user changed the default APN? If the user connects through 3G to the internet they have to go through an APN regardless.. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I want to display a messagebox to the user when he has connected to a custom apn, he has setup under the settings->add internet apn.

Comment: so I mean show different messageboxes depending on if he has set-up a custom APN or using an "default" apn, however both apn names are the same.

Comment: I seriously doubt this is possible. I'll walk the extra mile and mail a friend from Microsoft working on WP. Will keep you updated.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm either wondering, if it is possible.